# Why are some of my PowerShell scripts not invoking with System.Management.Automation WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, automation

```
namespace powershell_execution
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // function to create and execute an application to remove Microsoft.Calculator UWP app
        public void executeRemoval(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ex)
        {
            string appName = tbInput.Text.ToString();
            string command = $"Get-AppxPackage {appName} | Remove-AppxPackage";
            PowerShell.Create().AddScript(command).Invoke();
            // this command does not remove anything. I have admin access in my app manifest. "Start-Process notepad" as a command works fine.

            tbOutput.Text = command;
        }
    }
}
```

Why would "Start-Process notepad" invoke, but "Get-appxpackage *name* | Remove-appxpackage" or similar commands do not invoke?

Comment: I couldn't get task scheduler to run c# code in PowerShell unless I ran it as me. This looks more like a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the execution policy of PowerShell.

Comment: sadly its unrestricted already. Thank you.